# Why does scrartcl produce a line break within headings after a line-wrapped word?

Tags: koma-script

When using `\documentclass{article}`, the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl (Compound 1)}
\end{document}
```

will produce:
[image: article gives a result as expected]

If, however, the corresponding KOMA-Script class is used,

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl (Compound 1)}
\end{document}
```

will return:

[image: scrartcl will produce an unpleasant line break within the heading]

The line break between 'Compound' and '1' is obviously not necessary. One can prevent this by adding `~`, but without understanding why scrartcl behaves this way, I see it more as a workaround. I'm using pdflatex from an up-to-date TeX Live 2019. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1: Interesting!

Comment: Hyphenation in headings (and titles) should be considered as really bad typography. So this is actually a noproblem-problem. Always set headings with `\raggedright`.

Comment: Names of chemical structures may easily span two or more lines and thus require the specification of hyphenation patterns. And this is where I can't adjust content to better reflect typographical conventions and recommendations.

Comment: See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/247

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens is that a hyphen in the last-but-one line is deemed bad by TeX, which sets `\finalhyphendemerits=5000`.

With just two lines there would be a hyphenated word in the last-but-one line, so TeX prefers to make one line more.

Workaround: set, for section titles, `\finalhyphendemerits` to zero.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\raggedsection{\finalhyphendemerits=\z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl
(Compound 1)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the tie `Compound~1` is recommended in *all* contexts, but this is not the main point.

The same behavior can be replicated with `\raggedright` in normal text:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-%
methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl\-methyl (Compound 1)

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I add `\finalhyphendemerits=0` after `\raggedright`, the output is two-line long.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm with you concerning the `~` in this case where we're talking about referencing a named part of the document. Could you maybe briefly explain why the output of the KOMA-Script class differs in this case? You're talking about TeX specific behavior there.

Comment: @user18258 `scrartcl` uses `\raggedright`, whereas `article` doesn't. That's the main difference. Without `\raggedright`, creating a new line would have a very high cost, much more than the demerits for a final hyphen.

Comment: @user18258 I added an example with plain and simple `\raggedright`.